# Display drivers for RaspberryPi3B+

Tags: rpi.gpio, display, pi-3b+, driver

I am trying to get a 3.5 inch RPi Display working on my raspberry pi.

I have written my sd card with raspbian and the pi works well (red LCD glows all the time , and greed LCD flickers (fades on and off), but I still have my display with white colour(I mean, I have no installed drivers), so how can I resolve this problem?

Where can I find drivers that won`t crash my system(I crashed my x-server last time) and where should it go?

On the computer or inside sd-image of my sd card? How can I use my raspberry pi 3 b+ without installing drivers ?

I had tried to use HDMI for that but there is nothing successful

Display:https://pp.userapi.com/c851528/v851528963/a51d2/OzcZCyWVLCY.jpg

Comment: What display are you using?

Comment: 3.5 Inch Raspberry Pi 3B+ Display

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c851528/v851528963/a51d2/OzcZCyWVLCY.jpg

Comment: I suggest googling 'xpt2046 raspberry pi'

Comment: Are you looking for a driver for the display? (it is not clear, from you question)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, i am searching for an answer where i can find the driver and also can how can i use raspberry without driver for tft

Comment: Are you looking for a driver for **the display**? (it is not clear, from you question, or comment, what driver you are asking about).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor , yep

Comment: I have made some edits to your question, to make it clear that you are asking about a display driver, can you edit to fill in what the device is.